# Database Project Deployment Process

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I am trying to understand how database projects work in Visual Studio. Here is what I have done so far:

1. Created an SQL Express 2008 database in SQL Management Studio. (I can see the database and the tables in Server Explorer in Visual Studio)
2. Created a database project in Visual Studio and imported the objects from the database I previously created.

Now I'm stuck, when I try to deploy changes I made in Visual Studio I get an error:

> The file 'blah blah.mdf' cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database 'blah'

My end goal is to have the database in Visual Studio so I can add it under version control and deploy changes anyone in the team makes to the local database.

Comment: What are your deployment settings? Are you trying to recreate the database each time? Try deploying to a different instance of the db.

Comment: I want to avoid creating a new instance each time. My goal is to have the database schema under version control. Deployment is to a local instance of the database. Preserving the data would be good but not essential.

Comment: Thanks. Please share with us your deployment settings. I use database projects constantly (even earlier today), and have never seen this problem or anything like it. Try also increasing your build log verbosity so you can at least determine what part of the deployment is causing the problem.

Comment: Not sure what settings you mean. The project is set to build the deploy script and run it. The connection is set to the local database. I actually solved the problem by deleting the files under Storage/Files (i think it's under Data Objects or Database Objects). Any idea why this worked?

Comment: What do you mean `Storage/Files`? What's the full path?

Comment: `Schema Objects\Database Level Objects\Storage\Files` I deleted the 2 files in there.

Comment: Ok, it looks like you were trying to deploy the actual files! Removing them is a good plan. I'm not sure there's a deployment setting that says not to deploy those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the files under `Schema Objects\Database Level Objects\Storage\Files` fixed the error.